# slots are rendering and not the other elements?

Tags: javascript, html, stenciljs

How could I get the slots and the other elements to render?

This is the render function of my Stencil component:

```js
import {Component, h, Element, State} from "@stencil/core"

@Component({
    tag: 'base-offcanvas',
    styleUrl: 'base-offcanvas.css',
    shadow: false,
})
export class BaseOffcanvas{

    @Element() container: HTMLElement;

    @State() isOpen = true;

        close = () => {
        console.log('close');
        this.isOpen = false;
    };

    open = () => {
        this.isOpen = true;
        this.container.focus();
    };

    checkFocus = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (e.key === 'Escape') {
            this.close();
        }

        if (document.activeElement.closest('.offcanvas') === null) {
            this.container.focus();
        }

    };
    render() {
        return (
            <section ref={el => this.container = el} class={`offcanvas bg-white ${this.isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'}`} tabIndex={-1} onKeyUp={this.checkFocus}>
                <div class="offcanvas-header">
                    <slot name="heading" />
                </div>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.close}>X</button>
                <div class="offcanvas-content">
                    <slot name="content" />
                </div>
            </section>

        );
    }
}
```

This is me using it

```html
  <base-offcanvas>
    <h2 slot="heading">Offcanvas Header</h2>
    <p slot="content">Offcanvas content goes here</p>
  </base-offcanvas>
```

All that is rendered is the following and it *doesn't* include the `section` tag or `button` or wrapping `divs` and I'm wondering why.

```html
<base-offcanvas class="hydrated">
  <!----> 
  <h2 slot="heading">Offcanvas Header</h2> 
  <p slot="content">Offcanvas content goes here</p> 
</base-offcanvas>
```

I want all the other content in that render method to show up *and* the slots as well.

I tried adding named slots and expected other markup to exist alongside it.

Comment: Please provide more detail about how you are deploying and testing. You should see `class="hydrated"` on a component element when all is well - if that's missing it's a sign that things aren't loading properly.

Comment: @G.Tranter I've updated the post.  I see the hydrated class, but I also see this html comment

Comment: Please share the full code of your component. Also what browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The property decorated with `@Element()` is readonly. It is used to create a reference to the component host element, not for elements in general. Because you are trying to set `container` via `ref` in your render function, this throws an error which prevents the render from completing which is why you don't see the component rendered. Most likely you should see an error in the browser console.

Change `@Element() container: HTMLElement;` to `container: HTMLElement;` and it should work.